# Самый простой способ получения выбранных элементов в виде модели

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Использую Qt 5.12. В QTableView после выбора нескольких строк данные можно отправить в LimeReport, который в свою очередь принимает модель (QAbstractItemModel*). Очень удобный способ передачи данных. Но при таком способе передачи, в LimeReport уходит вся таблица, а мне надо только выделенные строки (которые в QItemSelectionModel).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как максимально упростить доступ к выбранным элементам модели?

Comment: Возможно, стоит сделать дополнительную прокси-модель, которая возвращала бы данные, соответствующие выделению.

Comment: Через прокси модель. Делаешь наследование от QAbstractProxyModel переопрелеяешь mapFromSource и вуаля. Короче, надо поработать

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо. Решил вопрос через QSortFilterProxyModel. После фильтрации её отдаю в LimeReport и все работает!

Comment: Для полноценного ответа на свой вопрос укажите особенности реализации вашей прокси модели, и как модель определяет выделенные элементы. Обычно selectionModel принадлежит представлению, а не модели.